# Change value of an input with javascript, .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to obtain the users location, then insert into two seperate `<input>` fields. The script works when trying to print to, `<p id="lat"></p>`. But not for the `<input>`.

```
<form>
    <input type="number" step="any" name="lat" id="lat" value="" />
    <input type="number" step="any" name="lng" id="lng" value="" />
</form>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Get current location</button>

<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("lat").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("lng").value;
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
        y.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
    }
</script>
```

What am I missing here? Have added `.value` to the end of the veriable, am wondering if its the `data` type and/or `step` values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` doesn't have an `innerHTML` because `x` is equal to the string value held within your `#lng` element. It isn't equal to the element itself.

Rather than setting `x` and `y` to the `value` of each of your elements, set them to your elements themselves:

```
var x = document.getElementById("lat");
var y = document.getElementById("lng");
```

Then you can set the value using `x.value` and `y.value` (`x.innerHTML` or `y.innerHTML`):

```
x.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
```

And:

```
function showPosition(position) {
    x.value = position.coords.latitude;
    y.value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, have tried that but its still not working. Is there a way I can log errors to the console?

Comment: @atoms you commented when I was editing my post. Please see my update.

Comment: perfect, many thanks James! Realise now I was repeating myself by setting the var.

Answer (score 1):

just set `x.value= position.coords.latitude;`

and remove initialize 
`x= document.getElementById("lat");`

```
var x = document.getElementById("lat");
    var y = document.getElementById("lng");
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
        x.value= position.coords.latitude;
        y.value= position.coords.longitude;
    }
```